# Collider (java processing)

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a basic game, where by hitting an object, the player loses a life. The way I wrote the code, this happens every time the object and the player touch. I want the player to lose only one life and not all of them. Any idea how to solve that? Thank you

```
  void colision() {
    for ( int i = 0; i<cant; i++ ) {


      if ( personaje.x > o[i].x && personaje.x < o[i].x + o[i].tam &&
        personaje.y > o[i].y && personaje.y < o[i].y + o[i].tam/2) {

        //if( dist(personaje.x, personaje.y, o[i].x, o[i].y ) < (personaje.ph/2 + o[i].tam/2) ){

        personaje.restarVida();
        personaje.reiniciar();

      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you keeping track of the players' lives? All you've shown us is the collision method, but then asked us about players' lives.

Comment: You will need to add some logic to 'debounce' the event from happening everytime it's detected that it's within the player after it happens once. You could add a boolean to the object to check whether it's already hit the player already or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin's suggestion of knocking the character back is great: that would ensure the collision condition would be true only once per collision as opposed continuously until the character moves out of the way. You may need to store the previous position **before** the collision occurred.

Another variant, without knocking the character back is to have a boolean variable that keeps track if character was previously being hit or not. You could then only subtract lives if the character is currently hit, but has not been previously hit.

Here's a snippet based on your code as a proof of concept:

```
void colision() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < cant; i++ ) {

        boolean estChocando = personaje.x > o[i].x && personaje.x < o[i].x + o[i].tam && 
                              personaje.y > o[i].y && personaje.y < o[i].y + o[i].tam/2;

      if (estChocando && !personaje.estabaChocando) {

        //if( dist(personaje.x, personaje.y, o[i].x, o[i].y ) < (personaje.ph/2 + o[i].tam/2) ){

        personaje.restarVida();
        personaje.reiniciar();

        // remember the character was hit, so this condition won't be met the next time around
        personaje.estabaChocando = true;

      }

      // reset character was hit flag if no longer colliding
      if(!estChocando && personaje.estabaChocando){
        personaje.estabaChocando = false;
      }

    }
  }
```

This assumes you've defined `boolean estabaChocando;` already in your character class.

Personally I'd go with Kevin's suggestion of knocking the character back as visually it will be easily understood, add to the physics/realism of the game and is so prevalent in so many classic games it's basically an [affordance](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/128479/what-are-affordances-in-game-design).

Here's an example based on the above:

```
void colision() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < cant; i++ ) {

        boolean estChocando = personaje.x > o[i].x && personaje.x < o[i].x + o[i].tam && 
                              personaje.y > o[i].y && personaje.y < o[i].y + o[i].tam/2;

      if (estChocando) {

        //if( dist(personaje.x, personaje.y, o[i].x, o[i].y ) < (personaje.ph/2 + o[i].tam/2) ){

        personaje.restarVida();
        personaje.reiniciar();

        // restore character to last non-collision position
        personaje.x = personaje.px;
        personaje.y = personaje.py;

      }

      // update position to restore to
      if(!estChocando){
        personaje.px = personaje.x;
        personaje.py = personaje.y;
      }

    }
  }
```

The above assumes you will add `px` and `py` properties alongside `x`,`y` to the character class (from which `personaje` is instanced).

This particular implementation might be bullet proof as it doesn't take into account in which direction the character and game objects are moving.

Another way would be start [using vectors](https://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/) which may feel intimidating at first, but they're really fun to play with and super useful for game development overall.

If you were to use vectors, you could easily increment the character's position by the negative velocity (or even a multiple of that) to kick the character in the opposite direction of travel (by a certain amount):

[image: megaman being hit]

Comment: As always, nice answer George. In fact, I'd recommend trying this approach before attempting mine, because implementing this is easier.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you're calling this function from inside your `draw()` function.

(Side note: please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected snippet so we don't have to guess.)

Remember that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second. So this code is going to run 60 times a second. In other words, as long as your objects are colliding, you're going to detect that collision 60 times per second.

To get around this, you generally want to move at least one of the objects the first time you detect the collision. The way you do this depends on how you want your game to work, but some examples could be removing the enemy completely, knocking your player back, or starting your player over from the start.